# Cannot resolve SQL Server CE provider factory by invariant name

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, machine.config

This line of code

```
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client");
```

throws this exception

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Failed to find or load the registered
>   .Net Framework Data Provider.

Although my machine.config file contains the following section

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add name="SQL Server CE Data Provider" invariant="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Compact Edition" type="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.SqlCeClientFactory, Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Am I missing something? Should I look somewhere else? Code like `DbProviderFactory factory = SqlCeProviderFactory.Instance` works fine.

Comment: I don't have any of the DLLs listed in Microsoft.* in the machine.config section for Sql Server Ce... I have System.Data.SqlServerCe v9.0.242.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [multiple SQL Server CE installs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920700). The [Visual Studio tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=877C0ADC-0347-4A47-B842-58FB71D159AC&displaylang=en) provides the server explorer and design components and places the SQL Server CE DLLs in a location local to Visual Studio. I needed to install the [runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=85e0c3ce-3fa1-453a-8ce9-af6ca20946c3) to get the data provider registered in the machine.config file.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012, the default **ProviderName** is `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0`.

This lets *me* find a factory by name:

```
String providerName = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";

DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
if (factory == null)
   throw new Exception("Unable to locate factory for " + providerName);

DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
conn.Open();
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.